# Use Regex to Find Search Pattern from Text File

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I'm writing a program where the user inputs a search pattern which is one word 12 characters or less. The word can be made up of any alpha-numeric combination. I am reading the data from a text file that the user inputs via command line argument. I am able to find the word, but also find unwanted embedded words. For example, If I'm searching "is" and my text file contains "This", it'll tell me it found the word when that is not the desired result.

I placed " " before and after the word, but that eliminates it finding the word if it is the first word in a line. Also, all of characters beside alphanumerics are delimiters. Therefore, if the text file contains "this-dog" and my search pattern is "this", I would want it to return "this" as a match. It should treat the - as a space. This is my code as of right now for this aspect of my program:

```
try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            boolean again = true;
            boolean notTheFirst = false;
            while (again) {


                    System.out.printf("%n%s", "Please enter a search pattern: ", "%n");
                    String wordToSearch = input.next();

                    if (wordToSearch.equals("EINPUT")) {
                        System.out.printf("%s", "Bye!");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }

                    String data;
                    int lineCount = 1;

                    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(this.inputPath.getPath())) {
                        File file1 = this.inputPath;
                        byte[] buffer2 = new byte[fis.available()];
                        fis.read(buffer2);
                        data = new String(buffer2);
                        Scanner in = new Scanner(data);

                        while (in.hasNextLine()) {

                            String line = in.nextLine();

                            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(wordToSearch);
                            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

                            if (matcher.find()) {
                                System.out.println("Line number " + lineCount);
                                String stringToFile = f.findWords(line, wordToSearch);
                                System.out.println();
                            }


                            lineCount++;    
                        }


                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "word boundary" terms to each end:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b" + wordToSearch + "\\b");
```

Comment: Hi Thank you. What if I want to do the same thing, but with a string? Can I do this? String fileText = "\\b" + str + "\\b";//text from file
            String searchWord = "\\b" + search + "\\b";//the word being searched

Comment: @austin that sounds like a separate question, however... what do I you mean by "String"? Can you give some examples?

Comment: I can ask in a separate question, but have edited my question with the examples.

Comment: @Austin by editing your question, you've made this answer irrelevant. This site is not about solving *your*  problem.  It's about helping *everyone*, so we want future visitors to be able to get help with a similar problem. Please ask a new question. I rolled back your edit. BTW the new code you posted was riddled with bugs. Somehow you have misunderstood my answer and applied it to everything. Just use the code in my answer *as is* and your new question my go away. The word boundaries should be added to the *regex only*.

Comment: This is exactly why I was hesitant in giving you the "specific examples" you requested. I indicated I had no issue posting another question. I think my edited code would have errors on two lines because those are the only two lines I made the changes. I'm a new programmer and was not aware that word boundary technique only applied to regex. Thank you again for the help. Leaving it "as is" would help my new question mostly go away, except in the case of embedded words.

Comment: @Austin what's an "embedded" word?

Comment: If my search pattern is "is", but one of my lines contain "this".

Comment: `Pattern.compile("\\bis\\b")` will match the word `"is"` and will not match the characters `is` within the word `"this"`. The expression `\b` matches the gap between a word character and a non-word character (or visa versa)

Comment: Yes, thank you. My edit had a separate class with Strings used for the match with the caret identifiers.